# wicket 6 change pageparameters onClose modalwindow

Tags: java, wicket, java-6, wicket-6, modal-window

I am using wicket 6.17.0 for building a application.
That application contains two pages, PollInvullenPage and PollAanmakenPage.
PollInvullenPage is used by user to fill in a existing poll created with PollAanmakenPage.
Now the application needs preview function in PollAanmakenPage.

The form on PollAanmakenPage is using Ajax.
So i want to use ModalWindow to render PollInvullenPage with specific pageparameters and a object with information for the PollInvullenPage in the session. 
Now when i close the ModalWindow the PollAanmakenPage is reloaded and the previous pageparameters from PollAanmakenPage are lost.

Now i want to set the pageparameters to a specifik value so the PollAanmakenPage knows that he needs to get the object from the session and load the page with this values.
But how can i do this.
I tried to set the pageparameters with the following ways:

1. [ModalWindow.CloseButtonCallback](http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.x/org/apache/wicket/extensions/ajax/markup/html/modal/ModalWindow.CloseButtonCallback.html#onCloseButtonClicked(org.apache.wicket.ajax.AjaxRequestTarget))
2. [ModalWindow.WindowCloseCallback](http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.x/org/apache/wicket/extensions/ajax/markup/html/modal/ModalWindow.WindowClosedCallback.html#onClose(org.apache.wicket.ajax.AjaxRequestTarget))

But both ways are not called when i close the modalWindow.
Has someone a working example or knows someone what i am doing wrong?

Thanks,

Harm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is solved.
It was a issue with one of the classes that wasn't serializable.

Harm